# Custom mime-type added via `.mime.types` not recognized

Tags: 22.04, configuration, mime-type

At the header of `/etc/mime.types` it says:

> Users can add their own types if they wish by creating a ".mime.types" file in their home directory.  Definitions included there will take precedence over those listed here.

I tried registering a mime-type for `.drawio` files via

```bash
touch ~/.mime.types
echo "text/drawio                                       drawio" >> ~/.mime.types
```

But it had no effect, even after rebooting: `.drawio`-files are still considered `text/plain` when inspecting with `mimetype`. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please see this: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-custom-user.html.en

Comment: @FedKad I did and this works. Still, does this mean the remark in `/etc/mime.types` is wrong? Should I open a bug report somewhere?

Comment: I think so... Possibly the comment is outdated...